# Flutter large sliverappbar not working with tabs

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

I have a `SliverAppBar.large` and `Tab` inside `NestedScrollView`. However the app bar not displaying properly. Title in app bar hides behind `Tabs` and a padding above appbar title is present while scrolling. Is this a bug ?

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> tabs = <String>['Tab 1', 'Tab 2'];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverAppBar.large(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  title: const Text('Books'),
                  forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: tabs.map((name) => Tab(text: name)).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: tabs.map((name) {
              return SafeArea(
                top: false,
                bottom: false,
                child: Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return CustomScrollView(
                      key: PageStorageKey<String>(name),
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverOverlapInjector(
                          handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                        ),
                        SliverPadding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                            itemExtent: 48.0,
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                              (context, index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                                );
                              },
                              childCount: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you solved this? same problem here